# What is the reason for Time Limit exceeded here

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

Given a linked list, rotate the list to the right by k places, where k is non-negative.

Here are some examples:

```
Input: 1->2->3->4->5->NULL, k = 2
Output: 4->5->1->2->3->NULL
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: 5->1->2->3->4->NULL
rotate 2 steps to the right: 4->5->1->2->3->NULL

Input: 0->1->2->NULL, k = 4
Output: 2->0->1->NULL
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: 2->0->1->NULL
rotate 2 steps to the right: 1->2->0->NULL
rotate 3 steps to the right: 0->1->2->NULL
rotate 4 steps to the right: 2->0->1->NULL
```

Code:

```py
class Solution:
    def rotateRight(self, head: ListNode, k: int) -> ListNode:
        if k < 0:
            return head

        if head is None or head.next is None:
            return head
        it = head
        while k != 0:
            while it.next.next is not None:
                it = it.next
            temp = it.next
            it.next = None
            temp.next = head
            head = temp
            it = head
            k -= 1
        return head
```

The above code is working fine for **k < 2000000**.

The test case that is failing is -

```
Last executed input:

[1,2,3]

2000000000

Error: Time Limit Exceeded
```

The time complexity will be O(k* length of the list), correct?

Comment: using two `while loop` is not efficient

Comment: For large values of `k`, you can cut out a lot of unnecessary work by using `k % length_of_list`.  (Rotating the list by N is useless, because the list ends up back in its original state.)